# UIScrollView with dynamically created UIButtons not Scrolling

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I am using Xcode 6.2 and Swift.  I have set up with storyboard a UIScrollView which I fill with varying numbers of programmatically created buttons. Each button varies in height due to the data contained.  All of this usually creates a list longer than a single screen thus requiring scroll ability.  As I loop and create each button I also adjust the height of the button to meet the needs of the content.  So, in short varying numbers of buttons of varying size.  I am able to set the height for the scrollView by summing up each buttons height during creation.  Suddenly I cannot scroll the buttons anymore.  I have tried many of the suggestions made on this site for other related questions but none fix my problem.

some code:

```
// Add constraints depending on what number button it is
let heightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: codeData, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(buttonHeight))
codeData.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

let leftMarginConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: codeData, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.scrollviewContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 900)

let rightMarginConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: codeData, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.scrollviewContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 900)

let topMarginConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: codeData, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.scrollviewContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(sumOfButtonTops))

self.scrollviewContentView.addConstraints([leftMarginConstraint,rightMarginConstraint, topMarginConstraint])

let contentViewHeight:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollviewContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.codeButtonArray[0], attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(sumOfButtonTops + 30))
```

Comment: Try to set contentSize of UIScrollView according to button size instead of its height.

Comment: can you paste code how you have set buttons into scroll view.?

Comment: Abdullah - Can you show me an example of setting contentSize in Swift?

Comment: It is hard to show code but I will try some: